# Disable rule for Sonar C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube, codacy

I’d like to disable certain rules for Sonar C# for my Codacy project. According to the SonarQube docs, I have to create an `.editorconfig` file, so I did:

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.S121.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.S3216.severity = none
```

However, Codacy does not seem to pick up the `.editorconfig` file - at least the warnings that should be disabled are still there.

What do I have to do to disable certain rules for Sonar C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question in Codacy's forum ([see here](https://community.codacy.com/t/disable-rule-for-sonar-c/846/4)). Here is the answer I got:

> Basically, the SonarLint.xml file should contain all and only the rules that you want to use in your repository.
> One of our engineers developed a script that’s going to the public repository codacy-sonar-csharp, fetches all the patterns used by default in Codacy’s Sonar tool, and creates a SonarLint.xml file with them.

And here the mentioned script:

```sh
#!/bin/env bash

container_id=$(docker create codacy-csharp:latest)
codacy_rules_file=/tmp/codacy-rules.json

# get all the rules defined for the tool from inside the docker container
docker cp $container_id:/docs/patterns.json $codacy_rules_file
docker rm $container_id

# obtain all ids of the rules we have enabled by default
rules_ids=$(cat $codacy_rules_file | jq -r '.patterns[] | select (.enabled == true) | .patternId')

cat << EOF > SonarLint.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnalysisInput>
<Rules>
EOF

for rule_id in $rules_ids
do
    echo -e "\t<Rule>\n\t\t<Key>$rule_id</Key>\n\t</Rule>\n" >> SonarLint.xml
done

cat << EOF >> SonarLint.xml
</Rules>
</AnalysisInput>
EOF
```